# How do I create "save as" and "load" dialogs to create/load json files/data within javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, save

I'm creating a small level editor, completely for personal offline use, for a game I'm creating.

How would I create save as/load buttons that could respectively save my level as json data, and read in previously saved data?

Thanks!

Comment: if the customized data is not shared, you can simply use localStorage to presist the data between reloads. you can also use an input[type=file]/dnd to let the app get data from a file on the user's hard drive, and a downloader (like https://github.com/rndme/download)  to turn app-created data into a file in the user's _downloads_ folder.

Comment: localStorage is perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't have access to the file system, which means that you can't read, load and save data from it.

However, in HTML5 there is an API to do that, and is programmable by Javascript. Here you have a tutorial about how to read and write data with [HTML5 filesystem API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/).